# Fetched data not available via useState within function but is available outside of said function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch data from and api and use that date in another function via useState. When I console the state variable outside of a function I can see the value but if I use it in another function in the same component it's empty string.

Shouldn't the state variable be available to that function?

```
const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
  const data = async () => {
    const { data } = await fetchData(id);
    setFetchedData(data.name);
  };
  data();
}, []);

console.log(“fetchedData”, fetchedData); // Shows the data

const functionThatNeedsFetchedData = () => {
    return fetchedData; // returns empty string
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two things,

- your effect doesn't explicitly depends on `id`
- if you use useCallback hook for your function, you can express you dependency on fetchedData

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const data = async () => {
    const { data } = await fetchData(id);
    setFetchedData(data.name);
  };
  data();
}, [id]);

const functionThatNeedsFetchedData = useCallback(() => {
    return fetchedData; // returns undefined
  }
}, [fetchedData]);
```

By the way, always be careful with use of `console.log` when debuging, since it's an asynchronous function !